# How to call a built-in function which is shadowed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, we have `maximum [1,2,3]` which returns the maximum element in the list.

But if we redefine it locally,

```
let maximum xs = head xs
```

(I know this is weird, but doesn't matter)

How could we call the original maximum function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can preface it with the module name to access the "original" function.

```haskell
Prelude.maximum [1, 2, 3]
-- or...
Data.List.maximum [1, 2, 3]
```

It isn't overloaded (if by which you mean in an object-oriented sense of overloading) as your original question was phrased, the original `maximum` is just hidden or "shadowed" by your local definition.